# Chinese remainder theorem for polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}_q[x]/(x^N+1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, cryptography

Let $\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_N$ be the $2N$-th roots of $q$, i.e. $\alpha_i^{2N}\equiv 1 \bmod q$.

So, $\alpha_i$'s are roots of $x^N+1$.

Then, by Chinese Remainder Theorem (CRT),

$$\mathbb{Z}_q[x]/(x^N+1) \cong \mathbb{Z}_q[x]/(x-\alpha_1) \times \cdots \times \mathbb{Z}_q[x]/(x-\alpha_N)$$
where $q=1 \bmod 2N$.

Why $q=1 \bmod 2N$? If $q$ is not, is the above CRT not satisfied?
Or do I know incorrect theorem? If I do, let me know the correct conditions and why the conditions are needed.

Comment: Is there any information about $q$?

Comment: $q$ is a prime.

Comment: Are you sure that $\alpha_i^{2N}\equiv 1\pmod{2N}$? I think it should be $\alpha_i^{2N}\equiv 1\pmod q$.

Comment: You write $2N$th roots of $N$, but it looks like you mean $2N$th roots of $1$. You write mod $N$, but I think you mean mod $q$. Please edit the question.

Comment: OMG. It is correct that $\alpha_i^{2N} \equiv 1 \mod q$.